# Read un-Formatted value of Excel date cell using POI in java

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have Excel sheet and column which is custom formatted to **dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm** but when i double click on the cell, I see the value as **22-09-2014  08:10:00** instead to formatted **22-09-2014  08:10**. When I read the cell using **POI** I get value formatted that is **22-09-2014  08:10** . How can I get the value which I see on double click.

Comment: The un-formatted value is something like `41904` (number of days since 1st Jan 1900), which is very easy to get in Apache POI. Not sure where your different formatted one is coming from?

Comment: yeah its excel date.I am using dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)

Comment: Apache POI can only give you data that's stored in the file itself, it can't help with what any given user interface (eg Excel or OpenOffice) happens to show differently between saves...